# Prolog- find any number above 0

Tags: prolog

I'm a bit surprised about this Prolog error. For `p(X) :- X > 0`:

```
?- p(X).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I assumed this would unify X with some value above 0.

Could someone explain why my intuition might be off here?

Comment: This because X must be a function or a number in order to use >/2: https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=arith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, arithmetic in prolog [isn't reversible](https://faculty.nps.edu/ncrowe/book/chap5.html), but you can use something like the following code snippet from the same source:

```
better_add(X,Y,S) :- not(var(X)), not(var(Y)), not(var(S)),
  Z is X + Y, Z=S.
better_add(X,Y,S) :- not(var(X)), not(var(Y)), var(S),
  S is X + Y.
better_add(X,Y,S) :- not(var(X)), var(Y), not(var(S)),
  Y is S - X.
better_add(X,Y,S) :- var(X), not(var(Y)), not(var(S)),
  X is S - Y.
```